# popup window outside click set to false [setOutsideTouchable(false)] does not work

Tags: android, popupwindow, layout-inflater

//create layoutinflator
        try {

```
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
```

//create view

```
        final View menuview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.dictionarylist));

        Button Menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Menu);

        Menu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(menuview);//initialize popupwindow

                pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                pw.update(0, 0, 200, 250);
                pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);//set outside touch to false
```

//onclick listener for the button inside popupwindow

```
                Button b1 = (Button) menuview.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
                b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    // @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        pw.dismiss();

                    }

                });
                Button b2 = (Button) menuview.findViewById(R.id.btnQuiz);
                b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    // @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }

                });
                Button b3 = (Button) menuview.findViewById(R.id.btnTopic);
                b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    // @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        InitialTask2 Task1 = new InitialTask2();
                        Task1.execute();

                    }

                });
                Button b4 = (Button) menuview
                        .findViewById(R.id.btnDictionarylist);
                b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    // @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        try{
                        if(getApplication() != null){
                            pw.dismiss();
                        }
                        else{
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setClass(getBaseContext(), Dictionarylist.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        }
                        }
                        catch(Exception x){
                            x.getMessage();
                        }

                    }

                });


            }

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    }
```

popup window outside click does not work `pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);`. When clicking outside the popup window it perform action placed behind the popup window i.e parent window.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
pw.setTouchable(true);    
pw.setFocusable(false);    
pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

When window touchable is `true`, focusable is `false`, `setOutsideTouchable()` works.

If `setOutsideTouchable(true)`, touch outside of popupwindow will dismiss, otherwise the outside of popupwindows still can be touchable without dismiss.

Comment: Great. I added `setTouchable(true) setFocusable(false) setOutsideTouchable(false)`, and all my stoopid Espresso tests that use `onView(withId(R.id.some_internal_spinner)).perform(click())` broke! Now I gotta use `if (!we_are_testing)` to pass the tests...

Answer (score 6):

To dismiss the popup window just add the following line of code

```
  popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
```

It worked for me and i am sure this is what you want.

Comment: +1 for `ColorDrawable()` because `BitmapDrawable()` is *deprecated*

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Its working for me

```
popUp.setOutsideTouchable(false);
popUp.setFocusable(true);
popUp.showAtLocation(this.layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```