# how to remove the outside touchable event for popupwindows in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my code ,I set outsidetouch listener false ,it is working fine for    below 6.0 version mobiles but not for 6.0.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                        = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                popupView6 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_not_enough_points, null);
                popupWindow2 = new PopupWindow(popupView6, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                popupWindow2.showAtLocation(popupView6, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                popupWindow2.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
popupWindow2.setTouchable(true);    
popupWindow2.setFocusable(false);    
popupWindow2.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

I have posted the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602132/2002625).

Comment: working fine for below 6.0 version mobile but for 6.0 version mobiles not working