# How to make PopupWindow not dismiss on background touch, and still able to enter text into its TextView

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I have an `Activity` with two `PopupWindow`, one a popup calculator which works fine, I can only dismiss it via clicking the close button and that is perfect. The second window (we'll call RW) has two `EditText` to input numbers, which may be got using the calculator or just known.

My problem is, if I click outside the RW it dismisses, if I change around the attributes it may not dismiss but then I can't fill in the text. I'll attach the appropriate code, but not all of it I can share.

What I need from RW is that I can fill in the `EditText` and it does not dismiss when clicking outside of it.

RW:

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(activity);
        popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(activity.getApplicationContext(),android.R.color.transparent)));
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602132/6329985

Answer (score 0):

just set setOutsideTouchable(false);  for your popUp window.

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(activity);
        popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(activity.getApplicationContext(),android.R.color.transparent)));
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that didn't work either, it still collapses on outside touch